# Article about how to Find Out which Friends Viewed your Facebook Profile: Bogus?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

I know this question is being tagged as "subjective", but I promise that its a very pointed question and very relevant to web programming and will provide a good understanding for people who may happen upon the thread in the future.

I found a Wiki that details a supposed procedure for figuring out the most recent viewers of one's Facebook profile: http://www.wikihow.com/See-Who-Views-Your-Facebook-Profile-the-Most. In short, `View Source` brings up a `Javascript` array that is

```
["InitialChatFriendsList", [], id1, id2, id3, ...]
```

where `id1, id2, id3, ...` are the profile ids of your friends, in order with `id1` correspond the friend who viewed your profile most recently. I have a few question based on my base level of understanding of web programming.

- Unless the author of the article works for Facebook, how can he possibly know what is generating that array? Maybe there's some other relevance algorithm that generates it.
- Wouldn't a data structure like that be stored on the backend?? It seems weird that such information would be so easy to obtain.

Just wondering if maybe you guys can set me straight.

Comment: He can't know that and the article is not true.

Answer (score 3):

**It's the other way around.** Yes, there is a list of your friends, ordered a certain way. But the order is not who's most interested in *you*, but who *you're* most interested in.

This interest level is calculated by Facebook, and I suppose it looks at your Likes, profile views, message activity, to calculate who you're most likely to be interested in, or who you want to talk to.

The list is used in the Facebook search bar. Type one letter, and your closest friends will appear first. If you've been crushing on someone and repeatedly viewing their page, then they'll be at the top of the results.

See [What is the significance of OrderedFriendsListInitialData?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13789565/what-is-the-significance-of-orderedfriendslistinitialdata)